# How to bind evil-leader keys for org-src-mode?

Tags: org-mode, evil

I want to bind evil leader keys for  `org-edit-src-save` and `org-edit-src-exit` in `org-src-mode`. And I have:

```
(evil-leader/set-key-for-mode 'org-src-mode
  "s" 'org-edit-src-save
  "'" 'org-edit-src-exit)
```

But it doesn't work.  What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

When we use `org-src-mode`, the major mode is changed to the language we are editing.

So `'org-src-mode` should change to the language mode or you can set it globally.
For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
|
#+END_SRC
```

(`C-c '`) then the major mode in new buffer is `emacs-lisp-mode`, not `org-src-mode`. So you should set evil-leader keys for `emacs-lisp-mode`, such as:

```
(evil-leader/set-key-for-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode
  "s" 'org-edit-src-save
  "'" 'org-edit-src-exit)
```

or, set it globally by:

```
(evil-leader/set-key
  "s" 'org-edit-src-save
  "'" 'org-edit-src-exit)
```

Comment: Welcome.  I have tried to improve the language of the post. I hope I have kept your meaning.